# Service REST format JSON Wordpress

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rest, format

I need help to solve a problem. I´m using Wordpress APIRest to get JSON from my page.

```
@Override
public void onFeed(JSONArray array) {

    posts=new ArrayList<>();

    int length=array.length();
    for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
        JSONObject object= array.optJSONObject(i);
        Spanned desc= Html.fromHtml(object.optString("excerpt"));
        //Spanned tit=Html.fromHtml(object.optString("title"));
        Post post=new Post(object.optString("title"), desc.toString(),object.optString("featured_image"));
        posts.add(post);
    }

    postAdapter.addAll(posts);
    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This function give me the JSON with this format:

```
"title":
    {
        "rendered": "TITLE POST"
    },
```

The problem is that i only want to get the title but the JSON let me the label "rendered" too. When I print it on my textfield it is: rendered: TITLE POST

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the "title" as follows,

```
String title = object.getJSONObject("title").getString("rendered");
```